# Sending form data with extra parameters through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a post request with the form data as well as some other parameters to my Codeigniter controller. This is the code I am using.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log('onto the function');
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    var google_name = profile.getName();
    var google_image = profile.getImageUrl();
    var google_email = profile.getEmail();
    console.log('got the details');
    console.log('submitting');
    var title = ('#title').val();
    var message = ('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/review/submit',
        data: {
            title,
            message,
            'google_name': google_name,
            'google_email': google_email,
            'google_image': google_image,
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('fuck');
        }
    });
}
```

I keep getting `$ is not defined` and I have no idea why that is, cause when I remove `$` it gives me `#title.val() is not a function`.

Comment: Jquery is not included in your file,or might not be able to load before you call $.ajax

Comment: I am loading jquery in my header file, inside the head tag even. @ShubhDixit

Comment: Try loading it after your html loads just before the function onSignIn

Comment: Hey, I tried that and I didn't get any error, I also didn't get any success message either, I am gonna see what's up with that. @ShubhDixit

Comment: Cool ,it might work this way

Comment: if $ is not working try Jquery('#title').val()

Comment: ('#title').val(); is a syntax err try $('#title').val(); instead.Ur jquery is not it seems

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are giving jquery reference with correct path to your code

Include bellow CDN link in your head section of code

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js